# Отправка данных через форму

Tags: php

Подскажите в чем проблема.После отправки формы делаю редирект на эту же страницу,но при обновлении страницы данные все равно повторно отправляются,хотя редирект выполняется.

```
<?php
    define("USERS_LOG",'users_log.txt');

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        $login = trim(strip_tags($_POST['login']));
        $password = trim(strip_tags($_POST['password']));
        $user = "$login $password\n";
        file_put_contents(USERS_LOG,$user,FILE_APPEND);
        header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
?>

<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    <p><input type="text" name="login" autocomplete="off"/></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit"/></p>    
</form>
```

Comment: По мнению Opera butterfly таки не отправляются. Редирект проходит нормально и идет get-запрос. При F5 тоже повторяется get.

Comment: и как быть тогда?

Comment: а зачем такие сложности? оставьте action="" и данные будут приходить на ту же страницу

Comment: мб какому нить конкретному браузеру `method="POST"` надо ?

Comment: Я проверил в мозиле этот код,отрабатывает как надо,хром почему то не хочет

Answer (score 2):

Поставьте **exit()** после **header('Location:...')**

```
header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
exit();

<form action="" method="post">...
```

Comment: Пробовал не помогло

Comment: попробуйте у полей input дополнительно указать аттрибут value=""

Comment: Народ поясните мне что происходит)) или я туплю,или тут что то не так.Ладно если постом отправлять данные и потом обновлять страницу они повторно отправляются это понятно,но после этого я заново перезапрашиваю страницу,тоесть уже выполняю гет запрос,и после нажатия на Ф5 опять передаются данные причем пустые,как такое возможно?

Comment: Бида-бида. Что за браузер? Попробуйте вести логгирование всех запросов от клиента, со всеми данными и заголовками.

Comment: Гугл хром,в других все нормально!

Comment: Вебкит всегда славился. Есть вот такое предположение: Когда вы делаете Location, хром совершает head запрос, сервер отвечает 304 Not modified, хром берёт данные из кэша, а там у него (в кэше) заполненная форма. Ну и так далее. 

Хотя это только предположение. Ведите логи - там увидите.

Comment: Задал подобный вопрос на киберфоруме,ответили что хром не загружает повторно страницу если урл совпадает,в этом и вся проблема!

Comment: header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
 header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", FALSE);
 header("Last-Modified: ". date("r") );
 header("Expires: ". date("r") );